# How can I get Depth(Distance) Data using Depth(ToF) Camera?(Galaxy Note 10+, Camera2 API)

Tags: android, android-camera2, galaxy

I'm working with Galaxy Note 10+ and Android Camera2 API.

What I want to do is to get depth(distance) data while I'm taking pictures.(on Preview, View Finder screen)

Like this screenshot of Quick Measure app, I think it's Samsung default app.

[Quick Measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St4Me.jpg)

When I tested my device on [Google Camera2Basic Sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Basic), I found out that the depth(ToF) camera isn't included to `availableCameras` list because it doesn't have [CameraMetadata.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_BACKWARD_COMPATIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_BACKWARD_COMPATIBLE) among its characteristics.
And the characteristic says

> Devices with the DEPTH_OUTPUT capability might not list this capability, indicating that they support only depth measurement, not standard color output.

I have no clue how to use this camera to get depth information.
Should I open more than one camera simultaneously?

Any helps or comments are appreciated!

Regards,
Lee

Comment: Did you solve this I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @MosheRabaev Please check this thread.

https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/access-to-tof-camera-depth-data-while-taking-pictures-note-10-camera2-api/2054